# Tor does not work since yesterday. There is no error log

Tags: error

I open my Tor Browser and nothing happens: it immediately says "Tor unexpectedly exited. This might be due to a bug in Tor itself, another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you restart Tor, the Tor Browser will not able to reach any websites. If the problem persists, please send a copy of your Tor Log to the support team."

There is nothing in the error log file. It's empty.

I tried reinstalling from scratch, it changed nothing. I tried reinstalling a very old version (7.0), but I still get the same error. I disabled my antivirus, firewall, everything. I never even touched my torrc file, I do not know what that is.

I am on Windows 10.

I did nothing special to trigger this behaviour (e.g. no updates).

Comment: That's often a sign of an anti-virus blocking Tor Browser. There was a Tor Browser update 2 days ago, so maybe yours auto-updated and your anti-virus is blocking the new version.

Comment: @Steve I only have Windows Defender and Firewall, no other antivirus. I would think that if Windows Defender suddenly started blocking Tor we would have a tsunami of posts like mine in this StackExchange...